# File / Folder navigation problem with the 'cd' command

Tags: command-line, cd-command

I used to use this command `cd /Foldername` to navigate the folder.
But I am facing a problem with this now I need to use this command `cd ~/foldername` for navigating.
Please have a look on the screen capture:
[image: click here to view the image]

The fact is how can I retrieve the old command?
I prefer the old command.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Instead copy & paste the text here and use [code formatting](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 2):

When you navigate through directories, if you start with `/` the command `cd` interprets that it's an **absolute** path:

```
$ cd /directory
```

means `(root)/directory`, not `/home/user/directory`.

`~` is an alias for `/home/user`

If you are in your home directory, and type `$ cd directory` (note there is no `/`), cd interprets as a **relative** directory, meaning reltive to your current directory.

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between the two commands.

`cd /foldername` changes your current working directory to `foldername` which lies directly under the root.

`cd ~/foldername` changes your current working directory to `foldername`, which lies under your home directory, which in most Linux distributions should be under `/home/<your-username>/foldername`.

Your error message tells you that currently there is no `foldername` under your root directory.